# Software updater can't load in MATE 16.04

Tags: updates, ubuntu-mate, gtk-2

I applied some theme just after installing Ubuntu MATE 16.04.

Now the software updater doesn't show up when called from the menu.

This is what it say in the terminal :

```
(update-manager:5977): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:27:35: Junk at end of value

(update-manager:5977): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:40:48: Junk at end of value

(update-manager:5977): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:48:46: Junk at end of value

(update-manager:5977): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:59:58: Junk at end of value

(update-manager:5977): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:70:46: Junk at end of value

(update-manager:5977): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:81:58: Junk at end of value
/usr/bin/update-manager:28: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UnitySupport.py:29: PyGIWarning: Dbusmenu was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Dbusmenu', '0.4') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Dbusmenu, Unity
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UnitySupport.py:29: PyGIWarning: Unity was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Unity', '7.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Dbusmenu, Unity
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: It is working now, yet it still has some GTK import errors reported - http://paste.ubuntu.com/19085549/ I guess all the development has gone to App Grid. I tried to remove update manager but it is tied to MATE desktop - http://paste.ubuntu.com/19085799/